# Django: Is there a way to add a model instance method to the admin?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm looking to add a method that my Ticket model has called process to the admin, so that I could click a link in the list view, and "process" my model instance (do an API call behind the scenes).

To clarify:

```
class Ticket(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def process(self):
        ... hardcore processing action ...
```

I need to add the `process()` method directly to the admin without using a separate function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to provide a small method in your ModelAdmin class that returns a link pointing at a view that calls your model method, and add the name of that method to the modeladmin's `list_display` tuple. You'll obviously also need to define this view itself, and a url that points to it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, thats possible; Check out this documentation, just what you need:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#ref-contrib-admin-actions

Comment: I'm not looking for that. Did you read my question? I already found that in here and on Django docs. I'm looking for a way to add a MODEL METHOD to the admin. Not a custom function.

Comment: You changed your question; And why don't you add a custom function that calls the model method? Does the same job I guess?